# Documentation on LDAP authentication in JAVA?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, ldap

I am creating Inter Staff application and I want to use JNDI for Ldap auth. So that any one who logs in to the system gets logged in all the work level application? I want to know best possible logic in java for this functionality.

Comment: You are looking for the keyword "Single Sign On". There are so many different approaches that its difficult to provide you significant information without more details.

Comment: Is this a Java EE app? Then perhaps you also want to consider searching under J2EE Security (for how to set up security and pass the credentials you acquire from the LDAP look up.

Comment: yes, This is Java EE app.I found Oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/trailmap.html.

Answer (score 0):

For the Standard Library implementation, see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jndi/

Under the section "JNDI Service Providers" there are links to the LDAP provider, documentation, and tutorials on how to perform LDAP authentication in Java.

[This page from the Apache Foundation](http://directory.apache.org/api/java-api.html) also lists several LDAP/Java libraries, and might provide some useful resources and alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful. Now I have to setup SSL on Tomcat. Because I have to use secure connection for LDAP query.